# Creating a restore point in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-preview, system-restore

So, since I've upgraded to Windows 10, my recovery drive can not save restore points. It used to work just fine before. I cant even press buttons in the recovery center. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How do I fix this?

OS: Windows 10 technical preview: Build 10162

Comment: Since Windows 10 has not released the final build yes, your options are likely limited to, reporting the bug and reinstalling Windows 10.

Comment: @Moab - the information you seek is indeed in the question :$

Comment: Check registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\SystemRestore" if there are any "disable" entries in the right pane delete them.

Comment: There is no SystemRestore key.

Comment: why do you want a restore point for your recovery drive? Select C: and try again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - He has a typical OEM machine.  A single HDD with 2 partitions.  His desire to place the restore points on another partition isn't unreasonable.